# Given the moment generating function of $X$, find the distribution of $X$

Tags: distributions, moment-generating-function

$X$ has MGF $m_{x}(t)=e^{2t}$ for any $t \in \mathbb{R}$. What is the distribution of $X$?

My instructor went about it like this:

$m_{x}(t)=E(e^{xt})=Ee^{2t}+e^{2t}$ Here I am really confused, how did $E(e^{xt})$ become what's on the right hand side of the equation? I wonder if I copied it down wrong...but can someone please explain what he was trying to get at here?

So $P(X=2)=1$ Also, this is assuming that $X$ is a continuous variable, correct? How can I tell from the problem that $X$ is continuous, not discrete?

Comment: It looks to me like either you have copying errors, or your instructor does, but the result is correct. The easy way to see it would be to start with $P(X=k)=1$ and compute the MGF ($e^{kt}$).

Comment: $X$ is $2$ with probability $1$.  You cannot tell from the moment generating function whether it can surely only take the value $2$, or almost surely; if the latter then you cannot tell whether it is a continuous random variable or a discrete random variable

Comment: @Henry It's definitely not continuous! There seem to be slight differences of opinion concerning what a discrete RV is. The commonest Web definition appears to be one with at most a countable range, but [more sophisticated definitions](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~lawler/probnotes.pdf) require only that the measure of some countable set of reals equal unity: that is, $\Pr(X\in A)=1$ for some countable $A\subset\mathbb{R}$. Under that definition, this $X$ is discrete no matter what.

Comment: @whuber: Would you say, with $X_i$ i.i.d normally distributed, that $Y=\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ was "a discrete random variable".  I do not think I would, though I would say it was "almost surely $E[X_i]$".

Comment: @Henry Thanks for the interesting example--it shows how the points you bring up can be important. In several senses $Y$ is a discrete RV. One sense is the definition I previously quoted, with $A=\{E[X_1]\}$. Another is that in many (most?) applications random variables are not functions but are actually equivalence classes of functions that are equal a.e.; in that sense $Y=E[X_1]$. It doesn't bother me that $Y$ is defined in terms of continuous RVs; after all, we cannot expect all properties of components of a sequence to persist in the limit.

Comment: @Henry saying that this limit is discrete is correct but this is like saying that the singleton $\{x\}$ is at most countable.

Comment: @Stéphane: I am making a slightly different point: the convergence of my example to a single value is (thanks to the strong law of large numbers) almost sure, but not sure, and other possible values of the limit of the mean (which together have probability $0$ but are not impossible) make up a continuous and uncountable set; in addition there are cases (again with combined probability $0$) where there is no convergence of the mean.

Comment: @whuber I'm skeptical about this sentence in the pdf of your link : *"Every random variable can be written as a sum of a discrete random variable and a continuous
random variable."*

Comment: @Henry Ah ok. But considering this point of view is useless in probability, isn't it ? Note that the context when you write $E[X_1]$ is the $L^1$-space of Lebesgue integration theory, which is not a space of functions but of equivalence classes of functions.

Comment: @Stéphane That assertion about the decomposition into a continuous and discrete RV is a simple consequence of the definitions (on p. 4). Note that a continuous RV need not be *absolutely continuous.*

Comment: @whuber Assume the law of $X$ is the sum of the Lebesgue measure on $[0,\frac12]$ and $\frac12\delta_1$. What would be this decomposition ?

Comment: @Stéphane I don't follow: you have given an explicit decomposition into a continuous and discrete measure, so there's nothing to do!

Comment: @whuber This is a decomposition of the *law* of $X$, not of $X$.

Comment: @Stéphane You are correct--I misread that section. Unless the statement is changed to refer to the *laws* (as you point out) instead of the RVs, or to change "sum" to "mixture," then it is indeed wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> $m_{x}(t)=E(e^{xt})=Ee^{2t}+e^{2t}$ Here I am really confused, how did $E(e^{xt})$ become what's on the right hand side of the equation?

Simply, the expectation of a constant $c$ is $c$.

Since $\mathbb E[e^{tX}]=e^{2t}$, by multiplying by the constant $e^{-2t}$ on both sides we obtain $\mathbb E[e^{t(X-2)}]=1$ for each $t$. Differentiating two times and taking the value $t=0$, we obtain that $\mathbb E[(X-2)^2]=0$, hence $\mathbb P(X=2)=1$.

We didn't make the assumption that $X$ is continuous.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have another small question. Does $E(e^{2t})=e^{2t}$? The expectation of a constant is just the constant itself, as you had said. I think my instructor meant to write $E(e^{xt})=E(e^{2t})=e^{2t}$. Even if the variable $t$ is there, can I still assume that $e^{2t}$ is a constant?

Comment: Yes because $e^{2t}$ is constant (it does not depend on $\omega$).

Answer (score 1):

Another proof that $X$ is the degenerate random variable almost surely equal to 2 consists in considering the *cumulant generating function* of $X$, defined as
$$
C_X(t) = \ln \bigl(m_X(t)\bigr).$$
The Taylor-MacLaurin expansion of $C_X$ around $0$ is $$C_X(t) = \kappa_1t + \frac{1}{2!}\kappa_2 t^2 + \ldots...$$ where the first two *cumulants* are $\kappa_1=\text{E}(X)$ and $\kappa_2=\text{Var}(X)$.

In your case, $C_X(t)=2t$, hence $\kappa_1=2$ and $\kappa_2=0$, wherefrom it is easy to conclude that $X=2$ a.s.

Note that the 'bare-hands' proof given @Davide has something close to this approach with the cumulant generating function. I prefer his more direct proof, but the cumulant generating function is good to know.